# How to use the right sql query to accomplish a task

Tags: sql-server

I wanna make [LA,LI,LS,LU,LX,LY] = LUFT as well as [XY,MN,ST] = BASE
Please see below for more understanding
That's my query:

```
SELECT 
[ABC] = 'LUFT',
ROUND(SUM([GWU VS]),1) AS [GWU LUFT],
[ABC] = 'BASE',
ROUND(SUM([GWU VS]),1) AS [GWU BASE]
FROM tbl1
WHERE [ABC]='LA' OR [ABC]='LI' OR [ABC]='LS' 
OR [ABC]='LU' OR [ABC]='LX' OR [ABC]='LY' 
AND
[ABC]='XY' OR [ABC]='MN' OR [ABC]='ST'
--GROUP BY [ABC]
--ORDER BY [ABC] ASC
```

My Table:

```
ABC    GWU VS
LA      100
LI      80
LS      50
LU      200
LX      220
LY      150
XY      450
MN      600
ST      85
```

But I'm getting the wrong results
What i really wanna archieve / expected result:

```
ABC      GWU VS
LUFT      800
BASE      1135
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide the results in the way you requested:

```
SELECT 
    'LUFT' as [ABC],
    ROUND(SUM([GWU VS]),1) AS [GWU VS]
FROM tbl1
WHERE ([ABC] IN ('LA','LI','LS','LU','LX','LY'))
UNION
SELECT 
    'BASE' as [ABC],
    ROUND(SUM([GWU VS]),1) AS [GWU VS]
FROM tbl1
WHERE ([ABC] IN ('LA','LI','LS'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`case` is the most obvious answer:

```
sum(case when [ABC] in ('LA', 'LI', ...) then [GWU VS] else 0 end) AS [GWU LUFT],
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Case` statement to make the `ABC` column into two groups then apply the `group by`. Try this.

```
SELECT ABC=CASE
            WHEN abc IN ( 'LA', 'LI', 'LS', 'LU','LX', 'LY' ) THEN 'LUFT'
            ELSE 'BASE'
           END,
       [GWU VS]=Sum([GWU VS])
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN abc IN ( 'LA', 'LI', 'LS', 'LU','LX', 'LY' ) THEN 'LUFT'
            ELSE 'BASE'
          END
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0919/1)